# How can we show the product of different type separately?

Tags: mysql, laravel, view, controller, laravel-8

I have two type of products. Book and cd. Book has number of pages and cd has playlength. I kept a condition for edit, update and delete and it's working fine. In index function of Product Controller, I showed all products and its showing but when I need to display it in product.blade.php what condition should be kept to show this product differently. For eg: if product is book it's page number should be shown and if it's cd then it's play length should be shown. The column in database is papl for both.

ProductController.php

```
     public function index()
            {
                $products=product::all();
                
                return view('mainAdmin/products', ['products'=>$products]);
                
            }

public function show(Product $product)
    {
        if($product->type == 'Book') 
        return view('mainAdmin/bookProduct', ['product'=>$product]);

        if($product->type=='cd') 
        return view('mainAdmin/cdProduct', ['product'=>$product]);
        //return view('singleProduct', ['product'=>$id]);
    }
```

products.blade.php

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
   
      Title:{{ $product->title}}<br>
      Type:{{ $product->type}}<br>
      Firstname:{{ $product->firstname}}<br>
      Surname:{{ $product->surname}}<br>
      Price:£{{ $product->price}}<br>
      PageNumber:{{ $product->papl }}<br>
      <a href="{{ route('singleProduct',$product->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Show</a>
      <a href="{{ route('editProduct',$product->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a><br/>
      <p>--------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
      
      @endforeach
```

Database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuvkS.jpg)

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: I am not able to show playlength for cd product type and no of pages for book product type. It's just listed the value but not according to product type.

Comment: can you provide store method of your controller?

Comment: @Sandhya if it is sloved then mark ir give what is it annswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use blade `@if @else`

```php
@foreach($products as $product)
   
Title:{{ $product->title}}<br>
Type:{{ $product->type}}<br>
Firstname:{{ $product->firstname}}<br>
Surname:{{ $product->surname}}<br>

@if ($product->type == 'cd')
Price:£{{ $product->price}}<br>
@endif

@if ($product->type == 'Book')
PageNumber:{{ $product->papl }}<br>
@endif

<a href="{{ route('singleProduct',$product->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Show</a>
<a href="{{ route('editProduct',$product->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a><br/>
<p>--------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>

@endforeach
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements